# Is this a 747 or a 380?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I got a video of a 4-engine jet landing at LAX on December 28, 2018 at 12:40 PM.  Here's some screen shots from the [video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/vsk4_ZRsFp0):

[image: Approach][image: Overhead][image: going, going, gone...]

I think it is a 380, but....

Comment: A380. The A380 has 2x3 trucks on the body gear (as seen in your pic), the 747 has 2x2 trucks.

Comment: That's the A380 with its 6 wheel inner main landing gear. 747s don't have 6 wheel boogies. The winglet is another good hint.

Comment: Also the A380 has the flight deck on the lower deck while on the 747 it is on the upper deck. In this case you can see the nose and the flight deck are fairly low on the hull of the plane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an **Airbus A380**.

There are probably many distinctive features. One of the easiest to see (in your third picture) are the **wingtip fences**:

[image: British Airways A380 wingtip]
<sup>(British Airways A380 wingtip, [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:British_Airways_Airbus_A380-841_F-WWSK_PAS_2013_10_Wingtip_device.jpg))</sup>

The 747 has no wingtip device (-100 to -300 models), winglets (-400 model) or raked wingtips (-8 model).

You can also clearly see the strong dihedral on the inner wing (see e.g. [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/what-designs-the-dihedral-angle-in-modern-airliners/91924#91924) for an explanation). Other distinctive features are the ram air outlets (easily visible in the second picture, see [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/what-are-these-panels-underneath-the-wing-root-of-a-a380/67759#67759) for more details) and of course the main body landing gear with 6 wheels as mentioned in the comments:

[image: screenshot from video]