# What is the small openining on the bottom right of door 4R of an Airbus A321?

Tags: airbus-a320, feature-identification

While observing taxiing A321 planes, I noticed that they had an open hatch-like opening on the bottom right of door 4R.  I marked it here on a picture I found online.

[image]

I could not locate it in the [Airbus A321 Aircraft Characteristics manual](https://www.airbus.com/content/dam/corporate-topics/publications/backgrounders/techdata/aircraft_characteristics/Airbus-Commercial-Aircraft-AC-A321.pdf).  What is it for?  Why was it open?  Does it stay open during flight?

Comment: The question [What is this device below the door of a 737](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24776/what-is-this-device-below-the-door-of-a-737-and-other-aircraft) and its answer are better than the suggested "What is this square hole for".