# At which point does an airliner start to pressurize/depressurize the cabin?

Tags: airliner, cabin-pressure

Do airliners start changing cabin pressure at takeoff or after reaching a certain altitude? Also when do they start depressurizing the cabin ?

Comment: see also this answer: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/16799/1467

Comment: [This diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0XX4.png) shows (dotted line) how "cabin altitude" is managed during the flight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cabin pressure is maintained automatically by a controller. Before the flight, the pilots will input two numbers: the cruise altitude and destination airport altitude. From these two inputs, the controller will manage the cabin pressure schedule automatically.

From the Boeing 737 FCOM:

> The cabin begins to pressurize on the ground at higher power settings.
>   (...)
>
> In the air, the auto controller maintains a proportional pressure
>   differential between airplane and cabin altitude. (...)
>
> The descent mode is activated when the airplane descends 0.25 psi
>   below the selected FLT ALT. The cabin begins a proportional descent to
>   slightly below the selected LAND ALT. (...)
>
> While taxiing in, the controller drives the outflow valve slowly to
>   the full open position depressurizing the cabin.

For passenger comfort, the controller is programmed so that the rate of cabin pressure change is kept to a minimum. The cabin is actually slightly pressurized on the ground both during takeoff and landing, i.e. the cabin altitude is *lower* can the outside altitude. It smoothly transitions to and from cruise cabin pressure as the plane climbs or descends.