# What's the reason for "pre-pressurization" of the cabin prior to liftoff?

Tags: aircraft-systems, cabin-pressure

I'm reading a Citation M2's Pilot Training Manual, and it says:

> ...When the throttles are advanced for takeoff, the bleed air turns on
>   (if not already on for heating), and the pressurization controller
>   starts closing the outflow valves to pressurize the airplane. The
>   cabin altitude may descend by as much as 200 feet during this
>   pre-pressutization prior to lift off.

What's the purpose of the pre-pressurization prior to lift off?

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16796/why-is-cabin-pressure-increased-above-ambient-pressure-on-the-ground